# sls deploy to AWS serverless API gateway through bash CICD pipeline does not fail for errors

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless

I have a `serverless-compose.yml` configuration file with 4 stacks, and when I run `sls deploy` in my CI/CD pipeline (bash runner), sometimes one of the stacks fail to deploy for various reasons. However, the overall exit code of `sls deploy` is considered successful, which prevents CI/CD pipeline from failing. This is causing false positive reports.
So how to make `sls deploy` command give exit code 1 when there is a failure in any of the stacks ?

my `serverless-compose.yml` file is

```
services:
  stack01:
    path: foo
  stack02:
    path: foo/bar/02
  stack03:
    path: foo/bar/03
  stack04:
    path: foo/bar/04
```

when i run bash CICD pipeline runner to deploy this hrough command
`sls deploy` i expect the pipeline to fail if atleast one of these 4 stacks fail.